# Edición de documento en MongoDB

Tags: nodejs, mongodb

Hago la edición de un documento, cada documento tiene un asociado el _id del usuario al que perteneces (vease modelo),pero cualquier usuario puede editar el documento que no le pertenece. Como evitar eso?

```
const {Schema, model} = require('mongoose');

const adjectiveSchema = new Schema({
    word: String,
    track: String,
    meaning: String,
    type: String,
    user: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User' } 
});

module.exports = model('adjectiveSchema',adjectiveSchema);
```

```
//3.- Editing of the word
adjective_Ctrl.editAdjectiveWord = async (req, res) => {
    //Obteniendo los datos enviados por el usuario con req.params.id
    const { word, track, meaning, type } = req.body;
    try {
        await adjectiveSchema.findByIdAndUpdate({'_id': req.params.id, 'user': req.user._id}, {
            word,
            track,
            meaning,
            type
        },(err, result)=>{
            if (err) return res.status(500).send({ message: 'Error when returning the adjectives' });
            res.json({
                result,
                messages: 'putWord (adjective)'
            });
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }

};
```

Comment: Esas condiciones puedes hacerlo en la vista dependiendo el rol de un usuario que vea o no el botón editar.

Comment: Falta información en tu pregunta para poder ayudarte. Por ejemplo, ¿cómo sabes qué usuario está realizando la consulta? Si deseas que cada usuario pueda editar sus propios documentos y no los de los demás, necesitas una forma de saber qué usuario está conectado. Existen muchas formas de implementar algo así, todas opinables. Te sugiero que leas un poco sobre la diferencia entre *autenticación* y *autorización*. Saludos

Comment: @Synay, tu comentario es válido, pero manejar autorización en la vista es un riesgo de seguridad. Siempre la autenticación y autorización se deben manejar del lado del servidor. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras no dije que le de autentificación ni autorización, obvio que no es lo más óptimo, pero angular tiene el `*ngIf` así que por ejemplo al loguearse los datos se pueden visualizar y pasarlos a través de variable de sesión u otro, podría pesarle su rol por ejemplo. Aún así, cualquier página es vulnerable si no está bien validada